# Type mismatch between long variable and list box in userform

Tags: excel, vba

Received [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/524zN.png) for a data entry user form I created and the debugger is pointing the error to my line of code that shows the userform:

```
Sub SubmitButton()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scholarship Data")

    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A] + 1   ' Error is in this line 

    With sh

        .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 1

        .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.txtFirst.Value

        .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.txtLast.Value

        .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.txtYear.Value

        .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.cmbSchool.Value

        .Cells(iRow, 7) = frmForm.cmbAward.Value

End With

End Sub
```

Any insight on what could be causing an error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/524zN.png) for a userform would be great!

I am following a data entry form tutorial on YouTube and copied exactly the code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atFOM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
   iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A] + 1
```

with

```
   `iRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA("Database!!A:A") + 1`
```

or

```
   `iRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA([Database!"A:A"]) + 1`
```

supposing that `Database` is a sheet name of the active workbook...

But, are you sure you do not need "Scholarship Data" sheet?

Comment: Not sure actually... think in the tutorial it was referring to the list box name where there is a little list box containing all the entries of the data entry form to submit to the sheet later on.  (See the image at the bottom of the tutorial I have been attempting to follow)